# How to run functions defined in .zshrc with system in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, zsh

This is my `.zshrc`:

```
hello() {
    echo "hello"
}
```

and my `test.rb`:

```
system "hello"
```

and it doesn't work. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won’t be able to call the shell function from Ruby. The `system` call is going to spawn a [non-interactive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch) child process Zsh.

Things to note:

1. `.zshrc` is only used with an interactive shell.
2. You can’t call shell functions from non-shell scripts. Even in scripts, they need to be `source`d first.

You can put the function into a tiny script and invoke it:

```
% <hello
#! /usr/bin/env zsh
hello() { echo "hello" }
hello
% chmod +x hello
```

Then in `test.rb`:

```
system "./hello"
```